# Learning Javascript - easy way to listen to onclick event for both choices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning javascript and I figured what best way to learn would be to make a game of TicTacToe (I made other very basic JavaScripts before this).

I'm wondering if their is an easier solution then what I'm trying to do at the moment.

I give the user an option if they want to be "x" or "o". I have two separate functions that fire off if they either choose "x" or "o".

Is there a way I can have just one function that can detect whether "x" or "o" was chosen then have another function begin right after that choice? (I'm thinking that it would be the function to draw out the tictactoe board).

You can see I was playing around with the `var userChoiceO=document.GetElementById("O");` and w`.addEventListener("click", userChoice);` but I am still learning and some of this is going over my head.

Any kind of advice would be kindly appreciated if I'm going in the right direction with this.

Here is a general idea of what I got so far:

```js
var userShape = 'X';


var playerX=document.getElementById("X");
var playerO=document.getElementById("O");

function userChoiceX () {
 userShape = 'X';
}

function userChoiceO() {
 userShape = '0';
}
```

```css
.XO {
 font-size:70px;
 text-align: center;
 
}

#X {
 color:#ff574f;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 6vw;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#X:hover {
 font-size:100px;
}

#O {
 color:#8cabec;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 6vw;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#O:hover {
 font-size:100px;
}
```

```html
   <p>Click on the shape you would like to play as</p>
   <div class="XO">
    <span id="X" class="X" onclick="userChoiceX()">X</span><span id="O" class="O" onclick="userChoiceO()">O</span>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the event handler with the parent of the two spans `<div class="XO" onclick="userChoice(event);">`,

then , `event.target` gives you the clicked span element:

```
   function userChoice(event) {
      if (event.target.id == 'X')
        return userChoiceX();
      else if (event.target.id == 'O')
       return userChoiceO();
   }
```

```js
var userShape = 'X';


var players=document.querySelector(".XO");

   function userChoice(event) {
  if (event.target.id == 'X')
    return userChoiceX();
  else if (event.target.id == 'O')
   return userChoiceO();
   }
function userChoiceX () {
 userShape = 'X';
}

function userChoiceO() {
 userShape = '0';
}
```

```css
.XO {
 font-size:70px;
 text-align: center;
 
}

#X {
 color:#ff574f;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 6vw;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#X:hover {
 font-size:100px;
}

#O {
 color:#8cabec;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 6vw;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#O:hover {
 font-size:100px;
}
```

```html
   <p>Click on the shape you would like to play as</p>
   <div class="XO" onclick="userChoice(event);">
    <span id="X" class="X" >X</span><span id="O" class="O" >O</span>
   </div>
```

Comment: yes. don't worry .. if u want best practices .. contact me ,  i will give you the best way to implement that game.

Comment: I would to know some of those best practices!

Answer (score 1):

Use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target#Example) with [document.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [*event.target*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). That way the HTML markup doesn't have JavaScript mixed-in (a.k.a. [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)), and there can be fewer issues with memory leaks that way (e.g. in case elements with event handlers are removed). The example below also uses [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) and [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check the class name of the element clicked on.

```js
//wait until the DOM is ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(domReadyEvent) {
   //observe clicks on the document
  document.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    if (clickEvent.target.className.indexOf('X') > -1) {
      console.log('clicked on X');
      //handle click on X
    } else if (clickEvent.target.className.indexOf('O') > -1) {
      console.log('clicked on O');
      //handle click on O
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.XO {
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
#X {
  color: #ff574f;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 6vw;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#X:hover {
  font-size: 100px;
}
#O {
  color: #8cabec;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 6vw;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#O:hover {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the shape you would like to play as</p>
<div class="XO">
  <span id="X" class="X">X</span><span id="O" class="O">O</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value as an argument..

make one function called `userChoice()` and make it such that it's turnwise using a variable `turn`

so your function becomes

```
turn = 'X'
function userChoice(){
   userShape = turn
   if(turn == 'X'){
     turn = 'Y'
   }
   else{
     turn = 'X'
   }
}
```